# CSS drop down menu on focus disappears when accessing with keyboard

Tags: css

I have a CSS drop down that appears on either mouse over or keyboard focus, and though the drop down is accessible with the mouse, when you try to access it with the keyboard the the drop down vanishes (but you still cycle through the items).

Anyone have some ideas on how to keep the drop down visible when accessing the drop down menu items with the keyboard? The CSS code is below.

You can access a demo at: http://testingtesting1.info/joomla-test/

the HTML code is generated by Joomla.

```
/* Parent menu items */
.h-nav {
    width:720px;
    height:90px;
}
.h-nav ul {
    left:0;
}
.h-nav li {
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.h-nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:33px 24px;
    margin:0;
    float:left;

}
.h-nav li a:hover, 
.h-nav li a:focus {
    background-color:#ffbb58;
}
.h-nav li.parent {
    background:url("../../images/standard/arrow-down.png")no-repeat right;
}
/* Sub menu links */
.h-nav li li a {
    text-align:left;
}

.h-nav li li a:hover,
.h-nav li li a:focus {
    text-decoration:underline; 
    background-color:transparent; /* hide the background-color:#ffbb58 */
}
/* 1st Sub menu dropdown */
.h-nav li.parent ul.nav-child {
    margin:4px auto;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-9999%; /* using margin-left instead of display:none; because display isn't read by screen readers */
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px;
    width:220px;
    background:url("../../images/standard/bg-submenu.png") repeat;
    z-index:9999;
    /*rounded corners - rounding only bottom corners */
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px 10px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px 10px;    
}
/* keeps the drop down visible when hovering over parent menu */
.h-nav li.parent:hover .nav-child,
.h-nav li.parent a:focus + ul.nav-child {
    margin:auto;
    top:90px;
}
/* Resize the padding for the drop down menu items */
.h-nav li li a {
    display:block;  
    padding:2px 25px;
}
```

Comment: LI elements are not able to _receive_ focus by default – if you want them to be able to do so, you have to use the `tabindex` attribute; see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute

Comment: So I have altered the code, editing the code above, correct the li:focus issue. So now now the drop down menu will  display on both mouse over and keyboard focus, but the drop down disappears when accessing the menu items in the drop down with the keyboard.

Comment: Well yes, because then the LI loses its focus again … building a keyboard-navigateable menu this way using :focus doesn’t really work.

Comment: OK - what do you recommend for a pure CSS drop down menu?

Comment: Well, anything that requires :hover is problematic on mobile devices (and for keyboard input), :focus doesn’t really work as we figured out – so that leaves :target. That could work for a menu with only two levels – main items would have to contain anchor links that could be clicked when :hover doesn’t work, and could show the submenu items using the :target pseudo selector.

Comment: hmm, that could work. But at this point I think I am going to just use javascript and go ahead and build a joomla module that will fit my needs. I would have had this done a lot sooner if there was not such a push for a pure CSS drop down menu. Thanks for the advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the ability to access the html and manually add a `tabindex`, or it is dynamically generated every time, you can use Javascript to add a `tabindex` to the `li` elements (this is with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.h-nav>li').attr('tabindex',0);
});
```

or regular Javascript:

```
window.onload=function(){
    menu = document.getElementById("h-nav")
    navElems = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(e = 0; e < navElems.length; e++){
        if(navElems[e].parentNode == menu){
            navElems[e].tabIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If you can't add a `tabindex`, I don't believe there is any other way to focus on the `li`

**EDIT 9/21/13**

This is not perfect, but it would be usable for keyboard only.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m82Wv/)

For it to work, you can't have a sub-ul that contains the li's with anchors; the anchors must be siblings. This solution uses the `~` selector, which unfortunately only applies to siblings after the targeted element, so it makes the anchors before the focused one disapear.

Comment: Unfrotuntally I cannot use any scripting. if I could thi swould be much easier. the menu must be full CSS.

Comment: So I have altered the code, editing the code above, correct the li:focus issue. So now now the drop down menu will  display on both mouse over and keyboard focus, but the drop down disappears when accessing the menu items in the drop down with the keyboard.